# How to mark request superglobals as deprecated

Tags: php, phpstorm, type-hinting

I am trying to work out a way to make `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` show up in PhpStorm as either a warning or deprecated, as I am relying on getting the values for these from a `RequestInterface` (PSR-7 style).

I have tried disabling the superglobals module, in language features, but I can get my .php file with the PHPDoc with `@deprecated` to be used, it seems to pick a random instance from the project instead. (Often from a test case where I am setting the `$_REQUEST` var to test some legacy code)

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. How can those superglobals ever get deprecated. Is there something that you know that we/I don't?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner The question is about an IDE; the OP wants to have those variables highlighted as deprecated code when editing.

Comment: lets say you did it, this would affect you version only, and if you dont want to use them for some reason that's your brains job, not IDE's.

Comment: @IMSoP I haven't grasped the question, my bad.

Comment: Yes but if everyone on the project is using Jetbrains they would all see the warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PhpStorm, you can override default stub files. To achieve this, you need to perform the following steps.

1. Clone https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/.
2. Navigate to *Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | PHP Runtime*.
3. Point *Advanced settings | Default stubs path* to the newly cloned repo.

[image]

4. Open *External Libraries | PHP Runtime | superglobals | _superglobals.php* in an editor or just navigate from any global variable usage to its declaration.
5. Start editing the files and agree to perform changes on a non-project file.

[image]

6. Add `@deprecated` to desired variables.

After that, all deprecated variables will be struck through in a completion popup.

[image]

Unfortunately, there's a bug which prevents them being marked as deprecated in an editor (see [WI-29019](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/WI-29019)). But I hope we'll fix it soon.

Also, please keep in mind that from now on stubs won't be updated together with PhpStorm. So you need to periodically pull updates from GitHub. Additionally, you can remove all directories from the cloned repo but `superglobals`. In this case, PhpStorm will use embedded stubs for the rest.